# I have deleted all files in server; still site is working?

Tags: php, joomla, ftp, server, cpanel

I am getting strange issue with joomla site.
I have deleted all files from server using Cpanel.
I have checked with FileZilla: All files are deleted.
But still website is working perfectly.

What can I do so I can able to find what is the issue ?

Comment: Have you a link to the site?

Answer (score 2):

1. I suggest double check if all the files in Public_html folder are
   deleted.
2. Clear your browser's cache.
3. Most probably, the site you deleted is already hosted on another server.
   Meaning when you tried to delete it, someone has already configured it on another server of his own. (This happens a lot in the Domain registration and Hosting industry).

Comment: 1. I have double checked folder there is only .htaccess 2. I have done that many times 3. how can I check  site is configured it on another server ... loggedin cpanel using http://www.sitename.no:2082/ ... Can you give some more information

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are deleting site from wrong server. Your site may be not resolving to your server and due to that it's online after deleting all files. You can check your site through temporary URL from your server using http://SERVER-IP/~CPUser-Name URL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by clearing the cache of my browser,
In Chrome, go to `More tools` then `clear browsing data` and then `caches images and files` and `clear data`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with wordpress site. It was showing home page even after deleting files in public_html folder I tried to clear catch. But later found that it was accessing files from my localhost and localhost folder on which I was working for same site was causing the trouble. I just changed its location by first turning off my laptop and then it solved my problem; I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure you deleted your site from the server, I had this same issue, the best way is to clear your browser's cache, it is a cache problem... better still if you restart your device.

CTRL + F5 should clear your cache

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and see if you can help us to resolve some questions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you cleared your browser's cache? :) e.g. `CTRL` + `F5`

Comment: This isn't an answer.  It is asking for question clarity and should be a comment under the question.